# jsDiff implementation in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, diff

How to implement [diff-match-patch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/diff-match-patch) or [jsDiff](https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff) in Angular 4?

I've tried

```
import DiffMatchPatch from 'diff-match-patch'

const dmp = new DiffMatchPatch()
const diff = dmp.diff_main('dogs bark', 'cats bark', null, null)
this.foo = diff
```

and binding it by

```
<div [innerHtml]="foo"></div>
```

but still don't really know how to bind result to my.component.html. Example above doesn't work as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jsDiff like so:

```
import * as jsdiff from 'diff'

...

const diff = jsdiff.diffLines(str1, str2)
```